# Installing IPython magic functions from a Python module

Tags: ipython, ipython-magic

I have written some IPython magic functions for my students, and I would like to have them installed using easy_install. So far the only way I have found is to copy a python file to a profile directory, but easy_install complains about a SandboxViolation when I do that.

Is there a way to install magic functions via setuptools?

Answer (score 3):

Any importable Python module can be an IPython extension - you install it in the normal location, and then add a `load_ipython_extension` function which registers your magic functions. See the documentation on [writing extensions](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/extensions/index.html#writing-extensions).

Then you run `%load_ext foo.bar` (where foo.bar is your module name) to load the extension. You can also set a config file to load it every time IPython is started, but I don't think there's any good way to automate setting this up when a module is installed.